# How do I generate an apk file from within the Android Phone?

Tags: android, apk

---

I plan to Create something similar to MIT's App Inventor combined with Scratch Programming functionality. What I want is to add objects and resources for creating small games for kids and then allow them to run directly from the phone (without using a PC like App Inventor does). Now I need to know How to convert those build projects into an apk So even they can run as stand alone apps in phone

e.g:

- Create a Small Object Bird in phone
- Give it a Direction to move Up-Down-right-Left
- Then Save this and convert it into an apk so that it can run as an
  stand alone app game( bird with 4 movements)

This was just an example and I intend to add functionality to make good apps in it too

---

I Saw F-droid repo which stores the apk and then loads into the phone but I want something which can store it in .myformat(just an example) and it gets converted to .apk so that it can be installed in any phone without the need of any other app

### OR

If it is possible to store .myformat(just an example) on web cloud and generate an apk from within the cloud and then install it in the phone ?

Comment: As an advance, you wont be able to do that in iPhone for sure. Not sure about the apk

Comment: I asked for an Android phone